# Open-Source приложения на ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Друзья, подскажите, существует ли какой-то ресурс, где можно было бы посмотреть приложения, созданные с помощью ASP.NET и паттерна MVC. Хотелось бы посмотреть, как грамотно строить приложения, как люди подходят к решению тех или иных задач. Всё, что удалось найти самому это сплошь и рядом интернет-магазины. Уверен, что с помощью такой великолепной технологии можно создавать еще много интересных вещей.

Comment: Ну на https://github.com/search?l=C%23&q=.net&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93 конечноже

Answer (score 1):

Ссылки на приложения написанный на asp.net mvc не нашел, но когда я только начинал изучать MVC использовал данный ресурс https://www.techdays.ru/videos/ASP.NET. А еще можно зарегистрировать на сайте http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/ и там найти видео-уроки о новых возможностях MVC